# Why does glibc disagree with the eventfd manpage?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, manpage

`man 2 eventfd` says:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    #include <sys/eventfd.h>
>
>    int eventfd(unsigned int initval, int flags);
> ```

but in `/usr/include/sys/eventfd.h` I see:

```
extern int eventfd (int __count, int __flags) __THROW;
```

I hit this because I needed to pass `eventfd` as a function pointer and I got a warning when it had the signature described in the manpage. Is this signature non-portable? Do I need to be aware of this in code I write?

Comment: in the glibc tree you've linked to it's `unsigned int __count`

Comment: Ask maintainers of glibc man page. Most likely, signature was changed but no one cared to update man page. You can even contribute and make a change yourself!

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Whoops, you're right, I had a braindead moment there. Looking at the history shows they changed it in 2014, which is an answer to my portability question. I've self-answered with the info below, but please feel free to replace it with your own and I'll accept it.

Comment: The man page is part of the [https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/](Linux man-pages) project. It's not maintained by the same people as glibc. The latest version of the `eventfd` man page in the Git repo still has the non-current declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature in glibc was changed in 2014 with [this commit](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=69eb9a183c19e8739065e430758e4d3a2c5e4f1a) to the glibc tree:

```
diff --git a/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/hppa/sys/eventfd.h b/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/hppa/sys/eventfd.h
index 2d198a8..a3c340e 100644 (file)
--- a/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/hppa/sys/eventfd.h
+++ b/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/hppa/sys/eventfd.h
@@ -40,7 +40,7 @@ __BEGIN_DECLS

 /* Return file descriptor for generic event channel.  Set initial
    value to COUNT.  */
-extern int eventfd (int __count, int __flags) __THROW;
+extern int eventfd (unsigned int __count, int __flags) __THROW;

 /* Read event counter and possibly wait for events.  */
 extern int eventfd_read (int __fd, eventfd_t *__value);
```

I suppose in terms of portability, then, if you have an old version of `glibc`, the best you can do is cast your pointer to `eventfd` to `int (*f)(unsigned int, int)`.